# LINQ to SQL: How to handle ambiguous column names when joining tables?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types, ambiguity

I'm going to bootstrap this question with a previous one I asked:
[LINQ to SQL: Multiple joins ON multiple Columns. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307731/linq-to-sql-multiple-joins-on-multiple-columns-is-this-possible)

So I have a LINQ query:

```
var query =
    from t1 in myTABLE1List // List<TABLE_1>
    join t2 in myTABLE1List
      on new { t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB } equals new { t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB }
    join t3 in myTABLE1List
      on new { t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB } equals new { t3.ColumnA, t3.ColumnB }
  select new {t1.ColumnA, t2.ColumnA, t3.ColumnA } // Duplicate Anon type 'ColumnA'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It will be a little redundant since all `ColumnA` will be equal because of the joins.

Comment: @Albin, ah yes you are right. This is just an example though. the columns I'm dealing with are not in the joins so they aren't necessarily equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With explicit naming of the properties of the anonymous type

```
select new {t1A = t1.ColumnA, t2A = t2.ColumnA, t3A = t3.ColumnA }
```