# Help with LINQ join

Tags: sql, linq, join

```
var q = (from Labels in dc.tblArtworkDataLabels select Labels).ToList();
```

But I need this to do the quivalent of:

```
SELECT     d.ID, d.labelID, d.dataID, d.data, l.templateID
FROM         tblArtworkDataLabels AS d INNER JOIN
                      tblArtworkData AS l ON d.dataID = l.ID
WHERE     (l.templateID = 238)
```

How do I do this in LINQ?

### Edit

Sorry!  Missed the WHERE clause on original statmenet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = dc.tblArtworkDataLabels
    .Join(dc.tblArtworkData, l => l.ID, d => d.dataID, (l, d) => new {l, d})
    .Select(o => new {
         Id = o.d.ID,
         LabelId = o.d.labelID,
         DataId = o.d.dataID, 
         Data = o.d.data, 
         TemplateId = o.l.templateID,
     })
    .Where(o => o.l.templateID == 238);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a correct foreign key on `tblArtworkData` to the primary key on the `tblArtworkDataLabels` and have imported them correctly into the DBML designer you can have LINQ2SQL implicitly creating the join:

```
from l in tblArtworkData
where l.templateID = 238
select new {
    Id = l.tblArtworkDataLabel.ID,
    LabelId = l.tblArtworkDataLabel.labelID,
    DataId = l.tblArtworkDataLabel.dataID,
    Data = l.tblArtworkDataLabel.data,
    TemplateId = l.templateID,
}
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307731/linq-to-sql-multiple-joins-on-multiple-columns-is-this-possible/5309754#5309754) on the question "LINQ to SQL: Multiple joins ON multiple Columns. Is this possible?" for how the implicit join translates to SQL.

### Edit:

In the case I misunderstood your relations and you have many `tblArtworkDataLabels` to one `tblArtworkData` you have to turn the query the other way around

```
from d in tblArtworkDataLabels
where d.tblArtworkData.templateID = 238
select new {
    Id = d.ID,
    LabelId = d.labelID,
    DataId = d.dataID,
    Data = d.data,
    TemplateId = d.tblArtworkData.templateID,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var q = (from Labels in dc.tblArtworkDataLabels
         join data in dc.tblArtworkData on Labels.ID equals data.DataID select Labels).ToList();
```