# Invalid Expression term Where

Tags: linq

I have following LINQ statement:

```
from o in Orders
                    join od in OrderDetails on o.OrderNumber equals od.OrderNumber
                    join r in RMAs on o.OrderNumber equals r.OrderNumber
                    join rd in RMADetails on r.RMAnumber equals rd.RMAnumber
                    from i in Inventory 
                    where( a => ( od.SKU == a.LocalSKU)).DefaultIfEmpty()//error is here
                    where (r.Status != "Pending" && od.Adjustment == false)
                    select new
                    {
                        r.Status,
                        o.Name,
                        o.Company,
                        o.Address,
                        o.Address2,
                        o.City,
                        o.State,
                        o.Country,
                        o.Email,
                        o.Zip,
                        o.Phone,
                        o.ShipName,
                        o.ShipCompany,
                        o.ShipAddress,
                        o.ShipAddress2,
                        o.ShipCity,
                        o.ShipCountry,
                        o.ShipState,
                        o.ShipPhone,
                        o.ShipZip,
                        o.OrderNumber,
                        o.ShippingTotal,
                        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                        SerialNumbers = rd.SerialNumbers ?? "",
                        o.SourceOrderID

                    }
```

It's giving `Invalid Where term`. What I want to use LEFT OUTER JOIN having SQL Equivalent `left join Inventory i on od.SKU = i.LocalSKU`

Comment: What 'a' means in your context? By the way: i have no idea why your answer has been downvoted...

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307731/linq-to-sql-multiple-joins-on-multiple-columns-is-this-possible ?

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes but having issue to use left join

Comment: Left join is possible to achieve this way: *from lo in lorem join ip in ipsum into grp from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()*

Comment: @MaciejLos so as per my original query in question it will be: `into inv from i in Inventory`?

Comment: Not sure.. i have no idea how your entity model looks like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
         var qry =  from o in Orders
                    join od in OrderDetails.Where(od=>od.Adjustment == false) on o.OrderNumber equals od.OrderNumber
                    join i in Inventory on i.LocalSKU equals od.SKU into grp
                    from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join r in RMAs.Where(r=>r != 'Pending') on o.OrderNumber equals r.OrderNumber
                    join rd in RMADetails on r.RMAnumber equals rd.RMAnumber
                    select new
                    {
                      //set of columns here
                    };
```