# LINQ to SQL ,Join tables to get distinct result?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query that will get me some distinct values from two SQL Server data tables.

I have two tables named, `Facility_Cost_TBL` and `Tenant_Bills_TBL`.
I then have a column that is named `Nursing_Home_Name` which I am trying to get the distinct data from.

This is my effort in LINQ , however it does not work,

```
var name = (from f in dataContext.Facility_Cost_TBLs
                join t in dataContext.Tenant_Bills_TBLs on f.Tenant_Code equals t.Tenant_Code
                where f.Tenant_Code == code && f.Date_Month == date.Month && f.Date_Year == date.Year
                select new {Facility_Cost_TBL = f, Tenant_Bills_TBL = t}).Distinct();
```

And this is a working SQL statement I made that does what I want via T-SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nursing_Home_Name 
         FROM (SELECT Nursing_Home_Name 
         FROM Facility_Cost_TBL 
         WHERE Date_Year = 2016 AND Date_Month = 10 AND Tenant_Code = 664250 
         UNION SELECT Nursing_Home_Name 
         FROM Tenant_Bills_TBL 
         WHERE Year_Data = 2016 AND Month_Data = 10 AND Tenant_Code = 664250) 
         a
```

Could someone show me what LINQ sytax AND what LINQ extension method query would look like?

Comment: In your `LINQ` join, shouldn't you be joining on `Year` and `Month` too?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, I don't know how to do that which is why this is not working.

Comment: The problem with your Linq statement is that it is doing an inner join and hence only returning results if you have entries if both tables.

Comment: @sgmoore, Thanks for the help, I didn't quite know what I was doing wrong. Still new to LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following

```
var names = ((from f in dataContext.Facility_Cost_TBLs 
                                          where f.Tenant_Code == "664250" && f.Date_Month == "10" && f.Date_Year == "2016"
                                          select new { Nursing_Home_Name = f.Nursing_Home_Name }).
                                          Union(
                                          from t in dataContext.Tenant_Bills_TBLs
                                          where t.Tenant_Code == "664250" && t.Date_Month == "10" && t.Date_Year == "2016"
                                          select new { Nursing_Home_Name = t.Nursing_Home_Name })).ToList();
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Interesting approach to this. I was looking for a single query if possible.

Comment: If you remove the `.ToList()` on the first two querys, then you will end up with one sql query.

Comment: There isn't any need to include the `.ToDistinct()` as `.Union` will automatically exclude duplicates.

Comment: Thank you @sgmoore and KyloRen Please review had modified solution :)

Comment: Thanks, now I see what I was doing wrong. I didn't think to use Union for a LINQ query. UV and marked the answer solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if this works. [LINQ to SQL: Multiple joins ON multiple Columns. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307731/linq-to-sql-multiple-joins-on-multiple-columns-is-this-possible)

```
var name = (from f in dataContext.Facility_Cost_TBLs
                join t in dataContext.Tenant_Bills_TBLs  equals on new { f.Tenant_Code, f.Date_Month, f.Date_Year } equals new { t.Tenant_Code, t.Date_Month, t.Date_Year } 
                where f.Tenant_Code == code && f.Date_Month == date.Month && f.Date_Year == date.Year
                select new {Facility_Cost_TBL = f, Tenant_Bills_TBL = t}).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I found @J-Mean 's method to be better for what I need. UP vote for the help.